# Swift 4 CGContext draw memory leak

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-graphics

I have this code for converting an `UIImage` to `[UInt8]` (the pixels)

```
extension UIImage {
func pixelData() -> [UInt8]? {
    let size = self.size
    let dataSize = size.width * size.height * 4
    var pixelData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(dataSize))
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    var context = CGContext(data: &pixelData,
                            width: Int(size.width),
                            height: Int(size.height),
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: 4 * Int(size.width),
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
    context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

    return pixelData
}
}
```

This function is called a lot of times, and through debugging I noticed that the draw call allocate +1MB(image size) that is not released after the end of the function.

In the memory debugging information these are the responsible callers for the most of the memory:

`Responsible Library: CoreGraphics`

`Responsible Caller: CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData`

Can someone help fix this memory leak please?

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: I remember just choosing a different approach to the problem. Didn't solve it. (just avoided).